# Declare scalar variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, declare, scalar

My problem is i want to use this local variable inside my update query, is there a way of doing this?

```
 DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+''',''' , '') + cast(int_guid as varchar(max)) 
    FROM ex_in
    SELECT '''' + @listStr + ''''
```

**Update query**

```
update dbo.ex_in
SET    int_action = CASE WHEN int_action = 120 THEN 110 WHEN int_action = 220 THEN 210 ELSE int_action END
WHERE  int_action IN (120,220)
       AND int_guid in(@listStr)
```

Comment: Can't you use it as a sub query

Comment: @sri What do you mean by sub query?

Comment: Like [Gordon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28835333/2246380) has used in his answer `in (SELECT int_guid FROM ex_in)`. Learn more [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I dont want to select all int_guid values from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do what you want that I can think of is using Dynamic SQL, like so:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX);

SET @sql = '
UPDATE dbo.ex_in
SET    int_action = CASE WHEN int_action = 120 THEN 110 
                         WHEN int_action = 220 THEN 210 
                         ELSE int_action 
                    END;
WHERE  int_action IN (120,220)
       AND int_guid IN (' + @listStr + ')
';

EXEC @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, because `in` on a string variable does not do what you expect.

But, why bother with the variable?  Just do:

```
update dbo.ex_in
    SET int_action = (CASE WHEN int_action = 120 THEN 110 WHEN int_action = 220 THEN 210 ELSE int_action END)
    WHERE int_action IN (120, 220) AND
          int_guid in (SELECT int_guid FROM ex_in);
```

Of course, now that I write this, the `in` logic is unnecessary, because there both queries are on the same table and there is no filtering.  Just use:

```
update dbo.ex_in
    SET int_action = (CASE WHEN int_action = 120 THEN 110 WHEN int_action = 220 THEN 210 ELSE int_action END)
    WHERE int_action IN (120, 220);
```

Comment: So there is no way i can use that variable @listStr for int_guid in? The list is gonna change very fast so its important it wont change on just int_action

Comment: The only way to use @listStr is to build a string with dynamic SQL and then execute that entire string...